# "recovery in the economy" VS "recovery of the economy"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Despite the sluggish recovery **in** the economy, XYZ posted better-than-expected results.
> 2. Despite the sluggish recovery **of** the economy, XYZ posted better-than-expected results.

Which prepostion is the best choice? Is the choice between in and of dependant on the context?

Comment: I bet for of.......1's nuance is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the two sentences you provide, I would choose *of* as the more common preposition.

[Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recovery%20in%20the%20economy%2C%20recovery%20of%20the%20economy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecovery%20in%20the%20economy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecovery%20of%20the%20economy%3B%2Cc0) supports this:

[image: recovery economy preposition]

---

You could also use one of the following:

> Despite a sluggish economical recovery, XYZ posted better-than-expected results.
>   Despite a slowly recovering economy, XYZ posted better-than-expected results.

In both variations, a preposition isn't needed at all.

However, [another look](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191467/recovery-in-the-economy-vs-recovery-of-the-economy) at Google Books NGram Viewer shows that *recovery of the economy* still seems to be the most common:

[image: recovering economy]

Comment: Do you feel any subtle differences?

Comment: @MikePhilip In general, no. It's just whichever sounds better. But if I had to give word associations: (1) *recovering economy* implies something that's ongoing; (2) in *economical recovery*, there's a hint of something *inexpensive*, because that's one of the senses of economical; (3) *in* could imply it's a recovery that's happening inside the economy; (4) *of* could imply a recovery belonging to the economy.